# What explain the expensiveness of laptop from System76?

Tags: linux, windows, laptop

What explain the expensiveness of laptop from System76? I don't understand...
Compare to a Windows 8 laptop with very similar configuration; the price is also pretty much the same. I was sure that with equivalent hardware, the GNU/Linux laptop would be mush more cheap...

For instance a System76 Kudu Professional is pretty much the same price of this Toshiba S70 but the Toshiba have a greater GPU, what explain that? Ubuntu cost nothing to System76 but Windows licence cost something to Toshiba. What am I missing? I really wanted the Kudu but I am not sure anymore...

[System76 Kudu Professional](https://www.system76.com/laptops/model/kudp1)

- $937.00
- Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit
- 17.3" 1080p Full High Definition Matte Display ( 1920 x 1080 )
- Intel High Definition Graphics 4600 4th Generation
- Intel Core i7-4700MQ Processor 2.4 GHz 6MB L3 Cache 4 Cores plus Hyperthreading 8 GB
- Dual Channel DDR3 SDRAM at 1600MHz - 2 X 4GB Full Size Backlit
- Keyboard with Numeric Keypad
- 1 TB 5400 RPM SATA II
- 8X DVD±R/RW/4X +DL
- Super-Multi Drive Intel Centrino 2230 - 802.11 b/g/n Wireless LAN + Bluetooth Combo Module

[Toshiba S70](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834216556CVF)

- $949.99
- Operating System Windows 8
- Screen Size 17.3"
- GPU NVIDIA GeForce GT 730M 2GB
- Intel Core i7 4700MQ 2.40GHz 6MB L3 Cache Max Turbo Frequency 3.4 GHz
- Memory 8GB 4GB x 2
- Keyboard Color: Tile Black w/BL
- HDD 1TB 5400rpm
- Optical Drive Type DVD Super Multi
- WLAN 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN with Bluetooth

Thanks.

Comment: They charge so much because they can?  They have very little competition in the general sense, not a great deal of companies, want to sell Linux laptops

Answer (score 2):

Probably the Kudu uses the Intel integrated graphics because there's a high-performance FOSS driver (and possibly it gives better battery life as well). For a business laptop, the GPU isn't so important.

Also, it's likely that the cost of a Windows license to Toshiba is a lot less than the cost to an individual. Microsoft undoubtedly gives large OEMs massive volume discounts, making free OSes a less attractive alternative.

EDIT: Also, the Kudu has a higher-capacity battery, and supports up to 2 SATA drives and one mSATA SSD, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The cost of the operating system is negligible compared to the rest of the laptop. This is even more true when considering high-end laptops.

There is another catch however. Not only does Microsoft self bulk licenses of Windows for very cheap, a high number of vendors get it for effectively a negative price! You see, Windows laptops often come with preloaded software, lots of it. These give a free trial to the user but they make it on the laptop because the companies you make those software *pay* computer makers to load their software.

*Think about it, why else would companies load their computers with such software? Actually, I know this first hand because I used to work for one of the involved parties.*

Comment: Yes, I neglected to mention the included bloatware. This does drive down the price of Windows PCs as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about ***Volume***, first and foremost.

In addition to what others have said, it also has to do with a somewhat better hardware of System76 (System76 you mention has 1920x1080, whereas [Toshiba only has 1600x900](http://www.toshiba.ca/productdetailpage.aspx?id=2147496276); System76 also seems to have been specifically engineered for better after-market expandability, which can also cut from the profits of being able to sell a higher end model, and sooner at that).